# How to handle scroll in a ListView? Listview autoload

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to handle the showing of the beginning and end of the list. 
I cant to use a scroll event, but I want handle the next event. (try to scroll list view without more elements). How to handle showing of a footer/header?

I saw the field "private EdgeEffect mEdgeGlowTop" in the class "AbsListView". thats fine! but it is private field and I can't to set listener or override this field...

Comment: Maybe I should to insert some object with listener? why?

Comment: Im really not truly understanding what you are trying to accomplish, are simply trying to HAVE a header and / or footer displayed in your list, or are you trying to implement some button that will take you to the bottom or top without swipe scrolling?

Comment: algorythm: manually scrolling; if header/footer are displayed - loading data. if footer are not displayed - handling onScroll event (_without_ loading). i havent a problem with onScroll, but i have problem with handling a footer/header. i should load data without scrolling too (for example, I have one item and onScroll event not executed). in the end I must have two event handlers: onScroll and onFooterShowed

Comment: I *think* what he is trying to do is the following: He has a lot of items in his list and does not want to load them all (as this takes a lot of time), so he just loads a chunk and whenever the list is scrolled to either one of the ends, the neighbouring chunk is loaded as well (and maybe some other far-away chunks are unloaded). Please tell us if that is not what you want.

Comment: @brimborium, you are right. I don't know how to correctly called the yellow gradient (see picture), so call it a footer/header :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't seem to be that clear. But as I understood you want to add Header/Footer while scrolling the ListView. Here is an example for adding footer  using [**Never Ending ListView**](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-tutorial-dynamicaly/)